# How to get the file size in shell script?

Tags: shell

How can I get the size of all the log file(*.log) inside the directory /Test*?
where Test* means Test-1 and Test-2 and Test-3 ...

Thanks and Regards,
Chandan

Comment: What have you tried yet? Did you already get the size of a single file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***du*** command:

```
du -shc /Test/Test* | tail -1
```

Replace the path `/Test/Test*` with your actual path(the needed folder)

An exemplary output should be like below:

```
144K    total
```

---

`-c` - to get a *grand* total file size

---

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html

Comment: That `-s` apparently shows the block size for the files. To see the actual size, use `-b`.

Comment: @JamesBrown, `-s ` (--summarize) if for **display only a total for each argument**

Comment: Poor choice of words, my bad (good morning, no coffee yet :). Use `-b` to see the actual size instead of block size. Btw, now testing, does that `-s` actually affect output in any way?

Comment: It seems this is giving me the size of all the Test* directory. but I need the size of only *.log file inside Test* and not the other file. Test* directory is also holding many other file.

Comment: @chandan, read my sentence about replacing folder path. Specify your actual path. It could be like `/Test/*.log`

Answer (score 1):

Using `stat` and awk for summing:

```
$ stat -c "%s" foo bar |awk '{i+=$1}END{print i}'
570
```